# Foreach product have a 'this' on click, submit with AJAX [Laravel]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a shop page and on it put a `foreach` to cycle through the products. On the 'Add To Cart' Button I made it go through an AJAX call and add the product through there. Although, I added another product and it doesn't work, not even the `CSRF_TOKEN or Data-ID`is logged when I do a test. (only on second product, first one works)

```
@foreach 

{{ $product->title }}
{{ $product->price }}

<form action="#" method="post">
<button class="btn btn-default" data-id="{{$product->slug}}" id="addCart" type="submit" >Add To Cart</button>
</form>

@endforeach
```

AJAX comes after this, it works, although I CANT get my data-id to even console log

```
$("#addCart").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
var slug = $(this).attr("data-id");

console.log(slug);

var csrf = "{{ csrf_token() }}"

console.log(csrf);
```

Comment: use class for multiple click operation not ID

Comment: You can't assign the same id selector, addCart, to multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of ID for the `click()` event and define ID with their own slug so that you can use using `.attr('id')`.

**Changes:**

```
<button class="btn btn-default addCart" id="{{$product->slug}}">Add To Cart</button>
```

**and**

```
$(".addCart").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var slug = $(this).attr("id");

    console.log(slug);
}
```

**Updated:** If you are creating multiple elements using loop, please use class for actions on them and use the ID to get unique value of those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your php Code section

```
 @foreach 

{{ $product->title }}
{{ $product->price }}

<form action="#" method="post">
<button class="btn btn-default addCart" data-id="{{$product->slug}}" 
type="submit" >Add To Cart</button>
</form>

@endforeach
```

change your js section like this.

```
$(".addCart").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
var slug = $(this).attr("data-id");
console.log(slug);
var csrf = "{{ csrf_token() }}"
console.log(csrf);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something like this in your controller action

```
return view('name.of.view', ['product' => $product]);
```

Your code works because you use that `$product` in your view, but you use `@foreach` the wrong way.

Change the action to:

```
public function index() 
{
    $products = Product::all(); // or whatever constrains you have

    return view('name.of.view', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

In your view:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
  {{ $product->title }}
  {{ $product->price }}

  <form action="#" method="post">
      <button class="btn btn-default" data-id="{{$product->slug}}" id="addCart" type="submit" >Add To Cart</button>
  </form>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You completely missed by question, although it is answered

Comment: Happy to hear that is solved. Wondering how your blade code works. I get an error when I use it.